# local variable referenced before assignment python issue

Tags: python, geocoding

So I'm coding a small project and I'm struggling with a certain aspect so far.

Here is the code:

```
import re

def clientDetails():
print("Welcome to the InHouse Solutions Room Painting Price Calculator")

print("STEP 1 - CLIENT DETAILS")
print("Please enter your full name")
userName = input(">>>")

print("Please enter your post code")
postCode = input(">>>")

print("Is your house a number, or a name?")
nameOrNumber = input(">>>")
if nameOrNumber == "number" or nameOrNumber == "Number":
    print("Please enter your house number")
    houseNumber = input(">>>")
elif nameOrNumber == "Name" or nameOrNumber == "name":
    print("Please enter your house name")
    houseName = input(">>>")

else:
    print("Invalid")

house = (houseNumber) + (houseName)
address = (postCode) + ", " + (house)       

print("Thank you for your information")
print (userName)
print (address)
print (" ")
print ("Is this information correct? Pleast enter Yes or No")
clientDetailsCorrect = input(">>>")
if clientDetailsCorrect == "no" or clientDetailsCorrect == "No":
    clientDetails()

clientDetails()
```

Not sure what's going wrong as I haven't actually referenced the variable anywhere else. Someone help.

Comment: Do you think you might like to tell us *which* variable is causing the error? Even better, show us the full error message? And fix your indentation, too.

Comment: I think indentation is also a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted the traceback.

That said, this line is the likely source of the problem:

```
house = (houseNumber) + (houseName)
```

The way your code is currently written, only one of `houseNumber` or `houseName` will be defined.  So Python is likely complaining about the missing one.

Given how your code looks so far, it's probably better to just do:

```
print("Please enter your house name or number")
house = input(">>>")
```

And remove the `house = (houseNumber) + (houseName)` line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def clientDetails():
    print("Welcome to the InHouse Solutions Room Painting Price Calculator\n")
    print("STEP 1 - CLIENT DETAILS")
    print("Please enter your full name")
    userName = raw_input(">>>")

    print("Please enter your post code")
    postCode = raw_input(">>>")

    print("Please enter your hose number or name")
    house = raw_input(">>>")

    address = "{}, {}".format(postCode, house)

    print("Thank you for your information.\n")
    print (userName)
    print (address)
    print (" ")
    print ("Is this information correct? Pleast enter Yes or No")
    clientDetailsCorrect = raw_input(">>>")
    if clientDetailsCorrect.lower().startswith('n'):
        clientDetails()
```

Using raw_input is better, it will input everything as a string. Also it will allow users to not type quotations to input text (I assume you will run this from CLI). If you later on need to separate houses that are numbers from names Python has very good string methods you can use to do so many wonderful things, I used a couple of them to simplify your code :)

N